# Modeling a FSM via Process1 transducer?

Tags: scalaz, scalaz-stream

I have a state machine that I would like to model using a scalaz-stream Process1.

The state machine models the message flow between a client and a server.

A basic set of data types might be:

```
sealed trait ServerState
case object Disconnected extends ServerState
case object Authenticating extends ServerState
case object Idle extends ServerState
case object Busy extends ServerState

sealed trait Message
case object Query extends Message
case object StartupMessage extends Message
case object AuthenticationOk extends Message
case object QueryResponse extends Message
```

In my head this would be modeled by a `Process1[I, O]`, where `type I = Message`and `type O =  scalaz.State[Message, ServerState]`.

It's like being a fog - I can see the outline of a solution but the firm definition of it escapes me.

Currently I have something that looks like this

```
type Transition = scalaz.State[Message, ServerState]
val connecting = Transition { StartupMessage => (StartupMessage, Authenticating) }
def fsm(state: Transition): Process1[Message, Transition] = {
  Await [Message, Transition] { msg =>
    case (connecting, AuthenticationOk) => Emit1(connecting) 
  }
}
```

I know this is wrong but I can't figure out where the State Transitions need to live.

Should the Process accept a `Message` and return a physical `ServerState` while the `Process1` driver handles the internal state?

I'm struggling to see how to "carry along" a message that cannot be executed at this time.

Example:

```
1. Current ServerState = Disconnected
2. StateMachine gets Query Message
3. StateMachine must send StartupMessage, ServerState now equals = Authenticating
4. StateMachine receives AuthenticationOk, ServerState now equals Idle
5. StateMachine must now sends original query message, ServerState now equals Busy
6. StateMachine gets QueryResponse, ServerState now equals Idle
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be able to encode your state machine through a recursive `Process1[Message, Message]` like this

```
def fsm(state: ServerState): Process1[Message, Message] = {
  receive1 { msg: Message =>
    (msg, state) match {
      case (Query, Disconnected) => 
        emit(StartupMessage) fby fsm(Authenticating)
       case (AuthenticationOk, Authenticating) => 
         fsm(Idle)
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

You might probably want to distinguish the `Message`s that your machine accepts as events (to trigger transitions) and the ones that it emits (as "actions") by having a `Process1[InMessage, OutMessage]`

Comment: I don't see any reason `init` would be needed inside of `go`, so the whole `go` layer isn't really necessary, right?

Comment: Oh, right I was taking that from some similar code I have where the init state is encapsulated. I'll edit the answer.